# Terraform - most recent AMI at time of apply is no longer the most recent

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We use the data resource to get the most recent AMI when we apply our terraform

```
data "aws_ami" "latest_ami" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["123456789"]
```

New AMIs are release monthly by a central team. We have various auto-scaling groups for the instances but they all use this 'latest AMI'

My question is, what happens if I apply the terraform to get this latest AMI (version 1), and then another AMI is released (version 2.0)? As we have Launch templates & configurations and I'm wondering what the easiest way to manage this is

We **don't** run the terraform monthly but if my instance gets terminated will my ASG know to get the newer AMI (version 2) or will it only be able to use the AMI that was retrieved when the terraform was applied (i.e. version 1)?

Comment: Are you creating instances via the `aws_instance` resource? Or as autoscaling groups and using launch configuration/templates to define the AMI? If it's the first then Terraform will detect the change in AMI and a plan will show it wants to destroy the instance and replace it with a new instance based off the new AMI. Autoscaling groups are more complicated depending on how you are using them so you'd need to expand your question to show that in more detail.

Comment: thanks, @ydaetskcoR, I have updated the question above. As we don't run the terraform monthly I don't know what the easiest way to manage this is so that the instances get the AMI version 2.0

Comment: ASG will launch AMI which is specified in its launch template.

Comment: You should edit your question to include how you are using the output of the `aws_ami` data source. Ideally this should be as a [mcve] with your data source, the launch configuration/template and also the ASG and then someone can tell you exactly what will happen when the AMI returned by the data source changes.